# Is there a way to recieve the responseObject out of the "onResponse" function?

Tags: java, android

How do I get the response out of the public void onResponse function?

Edit: I got Parse Error: "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'res'"

```
public JSONObject getRestRequest() {
    final JSONObject res; 

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, this.restPath, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { // basically I just want to return this response
            res = response;
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    );
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: using callback?

Comment: Use LiveData and update the response. In that case, new updates will be automatically returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do this exactly as you have written because the network request is happening on a separate thread.

First, let's walk through your code so you're clear what's happening:

```
public JSONObject getRestRequest() { // 1 - your method is invoked by another method and control starts here
    final JSONObject res; // 2 - This final (i.e. immutable) field is created

    // 3 - You create a new request object - no networking is happening yet
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, this.restPath, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { // basically I just want to return this response
            // 5 - Some time later, after the request completes, this method is invoked
            // BUT - you can't assign to res because it's final (immutable)
            res = response;
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    );

    // 4 - IMMEDIATELY after creating "request", the value that was created in step 2 (which is null) is returned
    return res;
}
```

So you're trying to execute an asynchronous operation (launching a thread to make a network request and parse the response) synchronously (blocking until it completes to return the result).

So that's your issue. To solve this, you have two options:

1 - Use an asynchronous callback:

```
public void getRestRequest(final Callback<JSONObject> callback) { // 1 - your method is invoked by another method and control starts here
    // Now you're passing in a callback that will be invoked later with the result
    // final JSONObject res; // 2 - You no longer need this local variable

    // 3 - You create a new request object - no networking is happening yet
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, this.restPath, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { // basically I just want to return this response
            // 5 - Some time later, after the request completes, this method is invoked
            // This time, you invoke your callback with the result
            callback.onSuccess(response)
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                // 6 - You can also pass back errors to your callback
                callback.onError(error);
            }
        }
    );

    // 4 - You return IMMEDIATELY after creating "request"
}
```

This method is more common. You create your callback, pass it in to the function and then just handle the response:

```
// 1 - Start showing some UI that a request is happening
showProgressDialog();

// 2 - A new callback to handle the network response is created - no request is happening yet
Callback<JSONObject> callback = new Callback<>() {
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
        // 4 - Some time later, when the network response finishes, this called
        // Handle response
        dismissProgressDialog(); // Back on the main thread, so safe to update the UI
    }

    public void onError(VolleyError error) {
        // 5 - Or this is called if the request failed
        // Handle error
        dismissProgressDialog(); // Back on the main thread, so safe to update the UI
    }
}
// 3 - Invoke the network request which will happen in a background thread.
// Meanwhile, the main (UI) thread is not blocked and the progress dialog continues to spin
network.getRestRequest(callback)
```

Option 2 - Use a [RequestFuture](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/d1a3d5388c79ff1a6fdb904daeff9b39d0bb7d26/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/RequestFuture.java).

```
public JSONObject getRestRequest() { // 1 - your method is invoked by another method and control starts here
    // 2 - Initialize a Future to use to synchronously get the result
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();

    // 3 - You create a new request object with the future as the listener - no networking is happening yet
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, this.restPath, future, future);

    // 4 - You return the value the future will obtain by making the network request
    // THIS IS A BLOCKING CALL SO DON'T DO THIS ON THE MAIN THREAD
    // This will also throw an exception if it fails
    return future.get();
}
```

So now you can get the result like you originally intended:

```
...
JSONObject response = network.getRestRequest()
...
```

But you *cannot* do this on the main (UI) thread (Android throws an exception if you try to do networking on the main thread. But if you're already doing work on a separate thread, this is fine.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get results immediately but request is asynchronous you can call request synchronously

```
synchronized (this) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { // basically I just want to return this response
            res = response;
            YourClassName.this.notify();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    );
    this.wait();
}
```

But it will lock your thread until request will be finished
i'm sure that you need to do it asynchronous 
please read documentation about multi threading in java

Comment: sorry
my mistake not 
            res.wait();
but
            this.wait();

Comment: thanks, I guessed I made i fault there

I forgot to write that i got a parse error: "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'res', maybe an idea?

Comment: try to make 1 element array, or move declaration of variable outside from function